# Get product's Reference Name for iOS In-App-Purchase product from within App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Is it possible for an app to retrieve the Reference Name of an iTunes Connect In-App-Purchase product?

The [SKProduct](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/) object only seems to give access to the product ID, the localized title and description, as well as pricing info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible.
Reference name is a internal name in iTunes Connect configuration.

> The product’s reference name is displayed in iTunes Connect and in Sales and Trends
>   reports. It isn’t displayed on the App Store.

You can't retrieve the Reference Name for an app.

Answer (score -1):

it's possible to Get product's Reference Name.Using below line you can get Reference name of product :

**product.localizedDescription**

Thank you.

Comment: Did you test it your self? can pls update the log as well

Comment: Who can read has a clear advantage. This is the localized description, not the   reference name.